# Using min_id in the Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, endpoint

Just the fact that I can find no-one else having this problem with the Instagram API indicates to me that I am doing something wrong.

If I was to enter: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/334250900/media/recent/?client_id=xxx&min_id=678453535718114828_919796408` and `678453535718114828_919796408` was the very latest post ID for that user, I should get nothing back, right?

Well I don't. I get one post back - the one in the `min_id` parameter.

The documentation states:

> MIN_ID - Return media ***later*** than this min_id.

but the behaviour seems to be to return media LATER OR EQUAL TO this min_id.

If I specify a min_id that is the THIRD most recent post, I should get TWO posts back, but no, I get three.

Sure, I can throw away the last result in the returned array, or do some checking to see whether I already have it - but that kinda defeats the purpose of the parameter.

Is it just me?

Comment: You are right, it is returning the min_id and later, you may have to throw away the last

Comment: I guess my ulterior motive is to have the folk at IG actually change the API to suit the documentation (and hopefully not vice versa, which might be easier!). In the meantime, I am just dealing with it.

Comment: You should submit a bug report to Instagram :) Little things like that tend to irritate developers and we don't like that haha

Comment: I did that. I've not heard anything, however. Not sure if I'm supposed to?

Comment: Is it an open bug reporting system that you can share a link to?